# Angular5 strange scroll when clicking anywhere on the component - Chrome

Tags: typescript, scroll, components, angular5

I am adding a new component in my application (this is an app that is already in production) I have an issue with the component. Every time I click anywhere within the component, it looks like something in the angular core is causing a scroll to the top of the page.

I added a click event to the component to see exactly where is going after that. I am not really sure how to stop this behaviour, I spent days trying to stop it but so far I haven't had any luck.

Please see some screenshots and code below (I cleared my component twice just to even show a piece of text and it still happens, so it isn't anything within the component - that I'm aware of)

Any help would be much appreciated

```
import { Component, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Transitions } from '../../../shared/services/transitions/transitions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-niche',
  templateUrl: 'src/app/html/details/panels/niche/niche.component.html',
  animations: [Transitions.fadeTransition(400)]
})

export class NicheComponent {
  @Input() isVisible: boolean;
  showHelpText = false;
  helpText = this.StaticMessages.nichePolicyTypeHelpText;

  constructor(@Inject('AppSettings')  public AppSettings?,
              @Inject('StaticMessages')  public StaticMessages?) {

  }

  returnFalse(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Template

```
<div *ngIf="isVisible" (click)="returnFalse($event)" @fade>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col col-sm-12 panel">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <h1 class="p-title">
          <span class="no-padding-x">What kind of niche policy are you looking for?</span><br/>
          <span class="no-padding-x"><i (click)="showHelpText = !showHelpText" class="material-icons cursor help-button">{{ (showHelpText) ? 'highlight_off' : 'info_outline' }}</i></span>
        </h1>
        <div class="help-content" [innerHtml]="helpText" *ngIf="showHelpText" @fade></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <mat-list id="niche-types" class="selectable-list">
          <mat-list-item>Test1</mat-list-item>
          <mat-list-item>Test2</mat-list-item>
          <mat-list-item>Test3</mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
</div>
```

it seems to be causing the scrolling (image of the line causing the scroll)

[image]

Comment: I got to the bottom of this. I had 2 components using the same template and they were causing that strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strange behaviour was caused by having 2 components using the same template.

I had this strange set up as the components code was in a shared npm package. I thought having the same template wouldn't affect the behaviour as I am not using one of the components but I was wrong.